# React loop output

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React / JS, so not sure how to do it.

Please see below my json, code, current output and expected output.

I've managed to get the current output but it's a slightly different json that has the date in the key under each title. Struggling with how to get the expected output.

Would be great if someone could assist.

Thanks

```
--- JSON ---
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "2018-12-05": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Title 1",
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Title 2",
            }
        ],
        "2019-01-12": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "Title 3",
            }            
        ]
    },
    "message": "Data retrieved successfully"
}

--- React code ---
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/names')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                names: result.data,
            });
        },
    )
}

render() {
    var { names } = this.state;
    return (
    {names.map(name => (
        <tr key={name.id}>
            <td scope="row">{name.title}</td>
        </tr>
    ))}
  );
}

--- Expected Output ---
2018-12-05
    Title 1
    Title 2
2019-01-12
    Title 3
```

Comment: so what do you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to `.map` over an Object (which is what `result.data` is). `.map` is generally only meant to be used on arrays.

What you'll want to do:

```
{Object.keys(names).map(date => (
    <tr key={date}>
        {date}
        {names[data].map(titleObj) => (<td scope="row">{titleObj.title}</td>)} // must be return
    </tr>
))}
```

*No promises I'm not missing a paren or bracket in there somewhere

Comment: I would add that he is not returning anything from the render method.

Comment: Thanks, getting a Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}" doesn't seem to like =>

Answer (score 0):

```
let { names } = this.state;

{
  for (let prop in names) {
    console.log(prop);
    names[prop].map(el => console.log(el.title));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but getting Parsing error: Unexpected token on line starting with for

Comment: oh sorry we can't loop inside render... try @Matthew Herbst -s example

https://codesandbox.io/s/9zkj4w634w

Comment: Thanks David and Matthew, appreciate it